Where is the Rambam buried?
I've heard different reports as to where Maimonides is buried. Where is his Kever located? I've seen videos saying that he's buried outside of Israel.

I have seen the kever in Tiberias.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_of_Maimonides

Assuming the site in Tiberias is actually where is buried, I've always found it a sad irony that massive memorial structures have been built over the site (seemingly increasing in size with every generation), despite his formulation of the halakhah as follows: ד  ומציינין את הקברות, ובונין נפש על הקבר; והצדיקים, אין בונים להם נפש על קברותיהן--דבריהם הם זכרונם.  ולא יפנה אדם לבקר הקברות.

The consensus (which is relatively well founded IMHO) is largely that he is buried in Tiberias, however there are other minority views that suggest he is buried in Hebron or Egypt. It would be interesting to see someone present these alternatives (even if only to debunk them) in the answers below.

Tiberias.
See this article on the website of the Maimonides Heritage Center: How do we Know Maimonides is Actually Buried in Tiberias?

when it comes to the burial site of Maimonides the tradition is almost as ancient as his death. The earliest source that identifies
Maimonides‟ burial site in Tiberias dates back to 1258 some 54 years
after Maimonides died.


If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

The Seder HaDorot writes explicitly that the rambam was buried in Tiberias.

What does this add beyond the previous answer?

A more reliable "jewish" source

What makes this source particularly reliable? Was the other source not Jewish?

may be the same according to the website terms but a book source is very much more reliable then a website when it comes to rabbinic writings

Id think that just depends on which book and which website
